# Create spark dataframe schema from json schema representation

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to serialize a dataframe schema to json and deserialize it later on?

The use case is simple: 
I have a json configuration file which contains the schema for dataframes I need to read.
I want to be able to create the default configuration from an existing schema (in a dataframe) and I want to be able to generate the relevant schema to be used later on by reading it from the json string.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

There are two steps for this: Creating the json from an existing dataframe and creating the schema from the previously saved json string.

**Creating the string from an existing dataframe**

```scala
    val schema = df.schema
    val jsonString = schema.json
```

**create a schema from json**

```scala
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataType, StructType}
    val newSchema = DataType.fromJson(jsonString).asInstanceOf[StructType]
```

Answer (score 77):

I am posting a pyspark version to a question answered by Assaf:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType    

# Save schema from the original DataFrame into json:
schema_json = df.schema.json()

# Restore schema from json:
import json
new_schema = StructType.fromJson(json.loads(schema_json))
```

Comment: Thanks! This sped up my data loading from a few minutes to a few seconds :D

Comment: Note: there's also `df.schema.jsonValue()` to get the json object (dict) instead of its string representation.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the answers above, I already had a custom PySpark Schema defined as follows:

```
custom_schema = StructType(
        [
            StructField("ID", StringType(), True),
            StructField("Name", StringType(), True),
        ]
    )
```

I converted it into JSON and saved as a file as follows:

```
with open("custom_schema.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(custom_schema.jsonValue(), f)
```

Now, you have a json file with schema defined which you can read as follows

```
with open("custom_schema.json") as f:
    new_schema = StructType.fromJson(json.load(f))
    print(new_schema)
```

Inspired from: [stefanthoss](https://gist.github.com/stefanthoss/33c2d1977e9adbd6b002348f8b3e6ed3)