# Reusing a schema in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am loading row-wise JSON data into Apache Spark on databricks, storing it in a date partitioned file.

I can import a full month without any issues, but want to import this data to append updates on a daily basis, so I write to parquet partitioned by date, creating a new date folder every day.

This usually works fine, but I recently had an issue where the new files were interpreted as a slightly different schema, causing some conflict.

So I tried to do the following:

```
schema = spark.read.format('parquet').load(parquet_path).schema
df = spark.read.json(json_path, schema=schema)
```

The operation succeeds, but loads 'null' into every single column of the dataframe `df`.

I've been able to replicate this even when reading the exact same data file that I sued to create the schema.

I'm at loss what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: did you tally both the old and new schema?

Comment: Are you sure you have json files in `parquet_path` and parquet files in `json_path`? :-)

Comment: I am sure I did in the actual app. above was an error. corrected.

Comment: see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40957585/create-spark-dataframe-schema-from-json-schema-representation/40957586