# How to validate my data with jsonSchema scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, jsonschema

I have a dataframe which looks like that

```
+--------------------+----------------+------+------+
|                 id |       migration|number|string|
+--------------------+----------------+------+------+
|[5e5db036e0403b1a.  |mig             |     1| str  |
+--------------------+----------------+------+------+
```

and I have a jsonSchema:

```
{
"title": "Section",
"type": "object",
"additionalProperties": false,
"required": ["migration", "id"],
"properties": {
  "migration": {
    "type": "string",
    "additionalProperties": false
  },
  "string": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "number": {
    "type": "number",
     "min": 0
  }
 }
}
```

I would like to validate the schema of my dataframe with my jsonSchema.
Thank you

Comment: POST a valid JSON with valid Spark schema JSON file.

Comment: I believe you're asking "what libraries can I use?". This sort of question is out of scope for StackOverflow as it usually attacks opinions or arguments. There's a list of JSON Schema implementations at http://json-schema.org/implementations.html however it doesn't include any for Scala. I suggest you google "JSON Schema Scala"

Comment: this is not a valid json schema for Spark, please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56339089/pyspark-create-schema-from-json-schema-involving-array-columns/56376821#56376821) for some ideas about applying json schema dynamically in Spark

Comment: json given is malformed. not able to parse it

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram should be good.

Comment: @abarriel check your json with https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=local.gadimo&right=local.qinixo its giving error also from code...  `                                               ; line: 9, column: 7]
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1581)` thats the reason answerer prepared new json not yours

Comment: @abarriel Can you please accept the answer or explain why it doesn't work you?

Answer (score 1):

Please find inline code comments for the explanation

```
val newSchema : StructType = DataType.fromJson("""{
                                        |  "type": "struct",
                                        |  "fields": [
                                        |    {
                                        |      "name": "id",
                                        |      "type": "string",
                                        |      "nullable": true,
                                        |      "metadata": {}
                                        |    },
                                        |    {
                                        |      "name": "migration",
                                        |      "type": "string",
                                        |      "nullable": true,
                                        |      "metadata": {}
                                        |    },
                                        |    {
                                        |      "name": "number",
                                        |      "type": "integer",
                                        |      "nullable": false,
                                        |      "metadata": {}
                                        |    },
                                        |    {
                                        |      "name": "string",
                                        |      "type": "string",
                                        |      "nullable": true,
                                        |      "metadata": {}
                                        |    }
                                        |  ]
                                        |}""".stripMargin).asInstanceOf[StructType] // Load you schema from JSON string


//    println(newSchema)
    val spark = Constant.getSparkSess // Create SparkSession object 

    //Correct data  
    val correctData: RDD[Row]  = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Row("5e5db036e0403b1a.","mig",1,"str")))
    val dfNew = spark.createDataFrame(correctData, newSchema) // validating the data

    dfNew.show()

    //InCorrect data  
    val inCorrectData: RDD[Row]  = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Row("5e5db036e0403b1a.",1,1,"str")))
    val dfInvalid = spark.createDataFrame(inCorrectData, newSchema) // validating the data which will throw RuntimeException: java.lang.Integer is not a valid external type for schema of string 
    dfInvalid.show()
    val res = spark.sql("") // Load the SQL dataframe
    val diffColumn : Seq[StructField] = res.schema.diff(newSchema) // compare SQL dataframe with JSON schema
    diffColumn.foreach(_.name) // Print the Diff columns
```

Comment: Thank you, but I already have a dataframe which came from spark.sql function.
I can't use createDataFrame when I have already a dataframe, and using collect will kill my perf..

Comment: updated column to display difference column.Based on diffColumn Seq[Column] size you can throw an exception or free to write any other logic around it.