# Databricks - explode JSON from SQL column with PySpark

Tags: json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

New to Databricks. Have a SQL database table that I am creating a dataframe from. One of the columns is a JSON string. I need to explode the nested JSON into multiple columns. Have used this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070251/pyspark-explode-json-in-column-to-multiple-columns) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36731674/re-using-a-schema-from-json-within-a-spark-dataframe-using-scala) to get me to where I am at now.

Example JSON:

`{
  "Module": {
    "PCBA Serial Number": "G7456789",
    "Manufacturing Designator": "DISNEY",
    "Firmware Version": "0.0.0",
    "Hardware Revision": "46858",
    "Manufacturing Date": "10/17/2018 4:04:25 PM",
    "Test Result": "Fail",
    "Test Start Time": "10/22/2018 6:14:14 AM",
    "Test End Time": "10/22/2018 6:16:11 AM"
  }`

Code so far:

```
    #define schema 
         schema = StructType(
          [
            StructField('Module',ArrayType(StructType(Seq
              StructField('PCBA Serial Number',StringType,True),
              StructField('Manufacturing Designator',StringType,True),
              StructField('Firmware Version',StringType,True),
              StructField('Hardware Revision',StringType,True),
              StructField('Test Result',StringType,True),
              StructField('Test Start Time',StringType,True),
              StructField('Test End Time',StringType,True))), True) ,True),
            StructField('Test Results',StringType(),True),
            StructField('HVM Code Errors',StringType(),True)
          ]

#use from_json to explode json by applying it to column
        df.withColumn("ActivityName", from_json("ActivityName", schema))\
            .select(col('ActivityName'))\
            .show()
```

Error:

```
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<command-1632344621139040>", line 10
    StructField('PCBA Serial Number',StringType,True),
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using **pyspark** then types should be **`StringType()`** instead of **`StringType`** and remove **`Seq`** replace it with `[]`

```
schema = StructType([StructField('Module',ArrayType(StructType([
    StructField('PCBA Serial Number',StringType(),True),
    StructField('Manufacturing Designator',StringType(),True),
    StructField('Firmware Version',StringType(),True),
    StructField('Hardware Revision',StringType(),True),
    StructField('Test Result',StringType(),True),
    StructField('Test Start Time',StringType(),True),
    StructField('Test End Time',StringType(),True)])), True),
StructField('Test Results',StringType(),True),
StructField('HVM Code Errors',StringType(),True)])
```

Comment: @N.Fisher, Did the answer helped?

Comment: This did help! I confused my syntax switching between Scala and Python